# Bootstrap 3 - more than 1 popup not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, popup, popupwindow

So in my webpage I have clickable image. `<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6 thumb">
                <a class="responsive" href="#test" data-toggle= "modal">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="image link" alt="">
                    name under the image
                </a>
            </div>`

which opens a popup
 `<div class = "modal fade" id = "test" role = "dialog">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <h4>test title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                <table class = "table table-hover">
                    <Thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Github</th>
                            <th>Topic</th>
                            <th>Install</th>
                        </tr>
                    </Thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class = "danger">Normal</td>
                            <td class = "info">No name yet</td>
                            <td class = "info">No author yet</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "#">Click here</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "#">Show</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "A link"</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class = "danger">Normal</td>
                            <td class = "info">No name ye</td>
                            <td class = "info">No author yet</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "#">Click here</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "#">Show</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "A link">Install</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class = "danger">Normal</td>
                            <td class = "info">No name yet</td>
                            <td class = "info">No author yet</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "#">Click here</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "#">Show</td>
                            <td class = "info"><a href = "A link">Install</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class = "modal-footer">
                <a class = "btn btn-default" data-dismiss = "modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>`

Then I decided to put another image with a different popup.
I copied the popup code below the first one and made another image but when I open the second image the background only greys and the popup doesn't come up.

However If I copy the second popup's code above the first one then the second popup works but not the first one that I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bjqd3kte). Your code should look like this. Pay attention to your ID. they should always be different for each modal.

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6 thumb"> <a class="responsive" href="#test" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div class="modal fade" id="test" role="dialog">

<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-6 thumb"> <a class="responsive"     href="#test2" data-toggle="modal">
...
<div class="modal fade" id="test2" role="dialog">
```